# iOS Swift Syntax for Mathjax

Tags: html, ios, syntax, mathjax

I wish to use MathJax to display a formatted math equation in a Web View.  I've seen various discussions on this topic, but they are mostly in Objective-C (I'm using Swift).

So far, I've dragged and dropped the "MathJax-master" folder into my Xcode project (i want the MathJax engine stored locally so no internet connection will be required for the app to work).  I next want to display ...maybe: **"Hello world, x = y^2"** in the Web View.

I found the following tutorial, but (again) I think it's in Objective-C, and I'm having trouble translating it into Swift syntax: http://new2objectivec.blogspot.com.au/2012/02/tutorial-how-to-setup-mathjax-locally.html

If anyone could please point me to the correct Swift syntax, it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Following code worked for me:

```swift
//Function below concatenates an HTML file String, stores it locally, then calls it to display in a UIWebView using NSURLRequest with MathJax typesetting:
func formatWebViewText(){
  //Specify the text that will go in the HTML file:
  let htmlString: NSString = "<head><script type=\"text/x-mathjax-config\">MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [ ['$','$'] ],},\"HTML-CSS\": { linebreaks: { automatic: true, width: \"container\" } } } )</script><script src='" +
  String(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MathJax", ofType: "js", inDirectory: "MathJax-masterSlim")!) +  //reference to local MathJax files
  "?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'></script></head>" +
  "<body>" + questionMessage + "</body></html>"   // "questionMessage" contains the text to be typeset/processed by MathJax
  
  //Give HTML file a name:
  let htmlFileName: NSString = "htmlTempFile.html"
  
  //Create a reference to the temporary directory that will store the HTML file:
  let tempDirectory: NSString = NSTemporaryDirectory()
  
  //Append reference temporary directory to include HTML file name:
  let htmlFilePath: NSString = tempDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(htmlFileName as String)
  
  //Convert appended temporary directory NSString to an NSURL object:
  htmlUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: htmlFilePath as String)
  
  
  //Below, HTML string is written to a file:
  do { try htmlString.writeToFile(htmlFilePath as String, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) }
  catch { }
  
  //HTML file URL is fetched and displayed in UIWebView:
  QuestionWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: htmlUrl!))
}
```

Comment: How to print mathjax vertical center in Webview

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 3

Here's your answer updated to Swift 3 and using a WKWebView (available in WebKit.framework and currently recommended by Apple over UIWebView and WebView):

```swift
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MathJax", ofType: "js", inDirectory: "MathJax-master") else { return }

let htmlString = "<head><script type=\"text/x-mathjax-config\">MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [ ['$','$'] ],},\"HTML-CSS\": { linebreaks: { automatic: true, width: \"container\" } } } )</script><script src='" + path +  //reference to local MathJax files
"?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'></script></head>" +
"<body>" + enteredLatex + "</body></html>"
let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("tempHTML.html")

do {
  try htmlString.write(toFile: filePath.path, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
} catch { return }

webView.load(URLRequest(url: filePath))
```